# R: list to data frame map function

Tags: r, list, dataframe, map-function

I have this list

```
my_list   list [3]                                       list length of 3

[[1]]     list [38 x 23] (S3: tbl_df, tbl, data.frame)   A tibble with 38 rows and 23 columns
[[2]]     list [38 x 23] (S3: tbl_df, tbl, data.frame)   A tibble with 38 rows and 23 columns
[[3]]     list [38 x 23] (S3: tbl_df, tbl, data.frame)   A tibble with 38 rows and 23 columns
```

I am trying to get a data frame (or a tibble) with 23 columns and 114 rows.

I have tried these codes

```
my_list %>% map(~ .,rbind.data.frame)
my_list %>% map(rbind.data.frame)
my_list %>% map(~ .,rbind.data.frame)
my_list %>% map(as.data.frame)
```

It works good only in console, but if I want to get the data frame to environment e.g.

```
my_list %>% map(~ .,rbind.data.frame) –> my_data_frame
```

I get a list again. What should I fix?

Comment: You mistake how `map()` works...! `rbind.data.frame` make no sense in your codes. Please read the document of `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [bind_rows](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html)

```
bind_rows(my_list)
```

will bind the three tibbles in the list together based on column names.